# XAML Trigger Auto-tab when MaxLength is Reached

Tags: wpf, xaml, datatrigger, maxlength

How can I incorporate an auto-tab when the MaxLength property is reached into a XAML Trigger, DataTrigger, PropertyTrigger, Style.Trigger, etc.  Below are two such options for how I have already accomplished this with a TextBox via code-behind.  I'm looking to apply it in a XAML style as well.  Thanks.

**XAML:**

```
<TextBox x:Name="MyTextBox"
            Text="{Binding Path=MyProperty}"
            Style="{StaticResource TextBoxStyle}"
            MaxLength="5"
            TextChanged="MyTextBox_TextChanged">
</TextBox>
```

**Code-Behind for WPF:**

```
private void MyTextBox_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (MyTextBox.Text.Length == MyTextBox.MaxLength)
    {
        Keyboard.Focus(NextTextBox);
    }
}

private void MyTextBox_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    // Auto-tab when maxlength is reached
        if (((TextBox)sender).MaxLength == ((TextBox)sender).Text.Length)
        {
            // move focus
            var ue = e.OriginalSource as FrameworkElement;
            e.Handled = true;
            ue.MoveFocus(new TraversalRequest(FocusNavigationDirection.Next));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can add a trigger into a control template for a length comparison, but it is impossible to move a focus in a xaml. There is nothing wrong with using code-behind.

Comment: I would be fine using code-behind, but I want to apply this to multiple Views and thought it better to use some sort of Trigger in the styles.  Can you show me an example of the control template you would use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

simply do this in your Shell.xaml

```
 <Style TargetType="TextBox">
                <EventSetter Event="TextChanged" Handler="MyTextBox_PreviewKeyDown"/>
            </Style>
```

and in your shell.xaml.cs

```
private void MyTextBox_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    // Auto-tab when maxlength is reached
        if (((TextBox)sender).MaxLength == ((TextBox)sender).Text.Length)
        {
            // move focus
            var ue = e.OriginalSource as FrameworkElement;
            e.Handled = true;
            ue.MoveFocus(new TraversalRequest(FocusNavigationDirection.Next));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: May be app.xaml and app.xaml.cs