# C# AutoTab when Textbox MaxLength is reached allowing delete

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm using WPF
I want to auto-tab to the next texbox when 'MaxLength' is reached.
I found this code : [XAML Trigger Auto-tab when MaxLength is Reached](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4340419/xaml-trigger-auto-tab-when-maxlength-is-reached)
And it's working. But the problem is, I can't delete text when the MaxLength is reached !
I can't change the actual text too.
Do you have an idea to allow me to modify, or delete text from a MaxLength reached textbox ?
**My XAML :**

```
<TextBox Grid.Column="0" Name="txtC1" Margin="5" MaxLength="7" PreviewKeyDown="txt1_PreviewKeyDown"></TextBox>
<TextBox Grid.Column="1" Name="txt2" Margin="5" MaxLength="12" PreviewKeyDown="txt2_PreviewKeyDown"></TextBox>
<TextBox Grid.Column="2" Name="txt3" Margin="5" MaxLength="12" PreviewKeyDown="txt3_PreviewKeyDown"></TextBox>
```

**Code Behind**

```
private void txt1_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, System.Windows.Input.KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        // Auto-tab when maxlength is reached
        if (((TextBox)sender).MaxLength == ((TextBox)sender).Text.Length)
        {
            // move focus
            var ue = e.OriginalSource as FrameworkElement;
            e.Handled = true;
            ue.MoveFocus(new TraversalRequest(FocusNavigationDirection.Next));
        }
    }
```

Comment: Could you add some code so we can see what you did? Thanks

Comment: Done, but it's same as the code on the link I posted.

Comment: I'm gonna do a test project on my side but what actually happen? When the text has reached the maxlengh you can't edit the content right at all?

Comment: Yes, because at key down, it automatically goes to the next textbox. I'm filtering for the back or delete key, but i don't know every deleting key, and I don't know how to know if something is selected in the TextBox, in wich case it would be editting, not adding text...

Comment: If [`TextBox.SelectionLength`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textbox.selectionlength(v=vs.110).aspx) is greater than zero there is selected text.

Comment: In my experience, this kind of "clever" behavior tends to aggravate rather than please end users.  And, as you've found, it's difficult to get right.  If I may suggest an alternative approach ... if you're looking for a telephone number (or any identifiable pattern), then validate the TextBox contents -
 I'd suggest in the TextChanged event - and if the contents are valid then switch focus to the next input control.  This would also allow you to extract the validation to a separate method rather than coupling it to a single control.

Comment: Yeah, that what I've proposed in my answer @David but I didn't explained it like you did thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are using the event on a keyDown and that means that when backspace or delete is pressed, the event is triggered but the text hasn't changed until the keyDown event is done, so the code will always validate with the same number of characters in the textBox and it will take one more character to type in the box to trigger the change of focus in your case.

You can do something like this instead
XAML

```
<TextBox Grid.Column="0" Name="txtC1" Margin="5" MaxLength="7" TextChanged="txt1_TextChanged"></TextBox>
<TextBox Grid.Column="1" Name="txt2" Margin="5" MaxLength="12" TextChanged="txt2_TextChanged"></TextBox>
<TextBox Grid.Column="2" Name="txt3" Margin="5" MaxLength="12" TextChanged="txt3_TextChanged"></TextBox>
```

Code

```
    private void txt1_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (((TextBox)sender).MaxLength == ((TextBox)sender).Text.Length)
        {
            // move focus
            var ue = e.OriginalSource as FrameworkElement;
            e.Handled = true;
            ue.MoveFocus(new TraversalRequest(FocusNavigationDirection.Next));
        }
    }
```

You can still do some keyDown event for something else e.g.: Allowing some key only like numbers or special numbers,  but it is better to validate the text lenght with a textChanged event.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved my own problem. Thanks to differents answers I got, I used them a little.
This is my new code behind :

```
private void txt1_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, System.Windows.Input.KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        // Auto-tab when maxlength is reached
        if (((TextBox)sender).MaxLength == ((TextBox)sender).Text.Length)
        {
            if(e.Key != Key.Delete && e.Key != Key.Clear && e.Key != Key.Back && ((TextBox)sender).SelectionLength == 0)
            {
                // move focus
                var ue = e.OriginalSource as FrameworkElement;
                e.Handled = true;
                ue.MoveFocus(new TraversalRequest(FocusNavigationDirection.Next));
            } 

        }
    }
```

And it's working.

Comment: Why you actually want to use the PreviewKeyDown? Because in your case, with the PreviewKeyDown event, if you put 5 characters in maxlengh, it will switch to the next focusNavigation at 6 because in the PreviewKeyDown event, the content of the text box hasn't changed so the maxLength will always say the number of characters before the keyDown

Comment: Didn't understand the problem you are talking about ?

Comment: The event you are triggering "PreviewKeyDown" is triggered/activated on a key press, so when you press almost any keys on your keyboard. The problem is when you go into your txt1_PreviewKeyDown function, the text in the textbox hasn't changed because the event happend before the text is changed with the key you pressed. So if you have "tes" in the text box and you press "t", you will enter the txt1_PreviewKeyDown function and the ((TextBox)sender).Text.Length value will be 3 instead of 4 like you would like.

Comment: Try that by addind a breakpoint in your code and compare how many characters there is in the textbox and the number the code gives you.

Comment: But that is exactly what I'm searching. I have 7 numbers in the TextBox. If I press a key, it's the eightth charcater in the textbox, and I don't want it. So I move to the next box !

Comment: I see what you do, you change the textbox on overflow instead of the way I saw it by changing it when the text has reached the 7th character. But when you press the 8th character, you loose it because you havent changed the focus on the next textBox yet.

Comment: Exact, I loose it. How can I keep the same behaviour as now, and keep the character ?

Comment: My solution that I gave does the job, it check the size when the text changed and if you maxLength is 7, when the 7th character is pressed, it will focus to the next textBox and your 8th character become the first one of the next. Or if you really want to stick with your method you can simply change your maxlength to 6 witch is not the perfect way to do it because it is not the number you are actually looking for.